# Removing folder Guzzle & Symfony after installing Omnipay

Tags: omnipay

I have installed Omnipay using composer in my local then upload it to my website and things work well.

When I remove folder Guzzle & Symfony, there are errors.

I want to reduce the number of files, so how could I remove these directories leaving only what I need for Omnipay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omnipay requires Guzzle & Symfony, so it's not possible to remove these two dependancies.

For example `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag` is used inside `Omnipay\Common\Message\AbstractRequest` to store values critical for the credit card transactions.

Guzzle is also used inside `AbstractRequest` (and therefor all of the gateways that extend from `AbstractRequest`) to perform all of the HTTP requests that are critical for transactions to be processed by your selected gateway.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment!